# Deserializing XML with namespace and multiple nested elements

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to deserialize the following xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ns2:myroot xmlns:ns2="http://jeson.com/">
  <item>
    <name>uno</name>
    <price>1.25</price>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>dos</name>
    <price>2.30</price>
  </item>
</ns2:myroot>
```

with these classes

```
public class item
{
    [XmlElement(Namespace="")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(Namespace = "")]
    public double price { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("myroot", Namespace="http://jeson.com/")]  //This was http://jeson.com, no slash at the end.
public class myrootNS
{
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "")]
    public item[] item { get; set; }
}
```

using this method

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), "http://jeson.com/");
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
using (StringReader textReader = new StringReader(xml))
{
    using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(textReader, settings))
    {
        return (T)serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
    }
}
```

but somehow I keep getting this error.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (2, 2). ---> 
System.InvalidOperationException: <myroot xmlns='http://jeson.com/'> was not expected.
```

What is the correct way of doing it ? The method works for deserializing without the namespace.

Comment: Turns out my namespace did not have slash at the end. As Alex points out, it should have.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that the namespace of myrootNS class is incorrect because it doesn't match the expected namespace in the XML.

```
[XmlRoot("myroot", Namespace = "http://jeson.com/")]
public class myrootNS
{
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "")]
    public item[] item { get; set; }
}
```

Notice that the `Namespace` property value has a trailing **/**. This is my deserialize method:

```
static T Deserialize<T>(string xml)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    using (StringReader textReader = new StringReader(xml))
    {
        using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(textReader, settings))
        {
            return (T)serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your code is fine, just add the / character at the end on the namespace in your myrootNS class, for that match with your xml expected.

Comment: In the XmlSerialezer constructor you don't need to specified the namespace, because you did in your myrootNS class. You can put XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

Comment: Did you try your suggestion? It broke one mine.

Comment: Sure, kindly share please :)

Comment: If it is specified in the XML file, it shouldn't be needed in the XmlRootAttribute. What is the workaround?

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to the `XmlRoot` attribute, you can also use the alternative `XmlRootAttribute` [constructor of `XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1wczcys(v=vs.110).aspx) to override when the element name or namespace differ:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(myrootNS), 
                     new XmlRootAttribute                             
                     { 
                         ElementName = "myroot", 
                         Namespace = "http://jeson.com/" 
                     });
```

Comment: Thank you, turns out specifying custom root name in poco is not enough, I have to specify it in the serializer too. Thank you.